# How to remove columns from array of struct by using a list of column name to be filtered If the array of struct is dynamic in nature

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an array of struct

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- index: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- failed_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: string (nullable = true)
```

I have to remove the column  from array of struct (webhooks) by taking the input from list 
eg filterList: List[String]= List("index","status")
I have to remove the columns which are not in list

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- index: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to do this operations by row level like By iterating each row not by the dataFrame level or not by using spark operations

Comment: can you post sample data ??

Comment: any good reason why not to use dataframe API functions?  And what do you mean by "spark"-functions? `Row` is also from spark

Comment: sorry for the wrong words basically mean by the operation like explode , groupby etc on dataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> val ddf = Seq(("fa1","fa11","fa111","fa1111","fa11111",Seq(("1","11","111","1111"))),("fb1","fb11","fb111","fb1111","fb11111",Seq(("2","22","222","2222")))).toDF("_id","h","inc","op","ts","webhooks").withColumn("webhooks",$"webhooks".cast("array<struct<index:string,failed_at:string,status:string,updated_at:string>>"))
ddf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_id: string, h: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> ddf.printSchema
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- h: string (nullable = true)
 |-- inc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- index: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- failed_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: string (nullable = true)


scala> ddf.show(false)
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|_id|h   |inc  |op    |ts     |webhooks            |
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|fa1|fa11|fa111|fa1111|fa11111|[[1, 11, 111, 1111]]|
|fb1|fb11|fb111|fb1111|fb11111|[[2, 22, 222, 2222]]|
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+


scala> val columsExceptWebhooks = ddf.columns.filterNot(_ == "webhooks").map(col(_))
columsExceptWebhooks: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(_id, h, inc, op, ts)

scala> val columnsRequiredInWebhooks = Seq("index","status").map(c => col(s"webhooks.${c}"))
columnsRequiredInWebhooks: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(webhooks.index, webhooks.status)

scala> ddf.withColumn("webhooks",explode($"webhooks")).select((columsExceptWebhooks :+ array(struct(columnsRequiredInWebhooks:_*)).as("webhook")):_*).show
+---+----+-----+------+-------+----------+
|_id|   h|  inc|    op|     ts|   webhook|
+---+----+-----+------+-------+----------+
|fa1|fa11|fa111|fa1111|fa11111|[[1, 111]]|
|fb1|fb11|fb111|fb1111|fb11111|[[2, 222]]|
+---+----+-----+------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks , But can we do this at row level like I am iterating through a row and  basically doing operations on the row

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this-

> please check the output column named `processed`

```scala
  val df = spark.range(2).withColumn("webhooks",
      array(
        struct(lit("index1").as("index"), lit("failed_at1").as("failed_at"),
        lit("status1").as("status"), lit("updated_at1").as("updated_at")),
        struct(lit("index2").as("index"), lit("failed_at2").as("failed_at"),
          lit("status2").as("status"), lit("updated_at2").as("updated_at"))
      )
    )
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |id |webhooks                                                                                |
      * +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |0  |[[index1, failed_at1, status1, updated_at1], [index2, failed_at2, status2, updated_at2]]|
      * |1  |[[index1, failed_at1, status1, updated_at1], [index2, failed_at2, status2, updated_at2]]|
      * +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      */

    val filterList: List[String]= List("index1","status1")
    val (index, status) = filterList.head -> filterList.last
    df.selectExpr( "webhooks",
      s"filter(webhooks, x -> array(x.index, x.status)=array('$index', '$status')) as processed")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
      * |webhooks                                                                                |processed                                   |
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
      * |[[index1, failed_at1, status1, updated_at1], [index2, failed_at2, status2, updated_at2]]|[[index1, failed_at1, status1, updated_at1]]|
      * |[[index1, failed_at1, status1, updated_at1], [index2, failed_at2, status2, updated_at2]]|[[index1, failed_at1, status1, updated_at1]]|
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+ 
      */
```

**I have added both column in the output namely `webhooks` and `processed` so that it can be easily compared. but for the output please check only `processed` column**

Comment: Thanks , But Can we do the operation you are doing on dataFrame on row , as I am passing to every function as a single row as arguments.

Comment: Yes the logic `s"filter(webhooks, x -> array(x.index, x.status)=array('$index', '$status')) as processed")` will be executed for each row in the dataframe